# hiding rows if data is not present in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have about 34,000 lines of data in a worksheet and I need too hide rows that does not have matching data in another worksheet. I have some code but i seems to hide all the data instead of jst hiding the data which is not represented in the other worksheet. The code is shown below and any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub HideCells()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
Dim valueToFind
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long

Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Køb VT nummer")
lastrow = xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("køb total")
lastrow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Debug.Print lastrow
Debug.Print lastrow2

For i = 2 To lastrow2

valueToFind = Sheets("køb total").Cells(i, 7).Value

For Each xlCell In xlRange
    If Not xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then
        Worksheets("Køb total").Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next xlCell

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd put a `Debug.Print` inside the loop indicating what the value of each cell being examined is, and maybe even having it print out `xlCell.Value = valueToFind` to see how it is evaluating the test.

Comment: debug.print shows that it is the right value it is trying to look up. could it be the loop it self with for each? im thing it might hide the row if it is not in the first row on the other sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a line containing "ValueToFind" for one value of "i" doesn't necessarily contain it for a different value of "i"

Try

```
Worksheets("Køb total").usedRange.rows.hidden = true

For i = 2 To lastrow2

    valueToFind = Sheets("køb total").Cells(i, 7).Value

    For Each xlCell In xlRange
        If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then
            Worksheets("Køb total").Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next xlCell

Next i
```

Comment: Changing it to your suggestion makes it hide all rows on the sheet it is supposed to look at to see if it should hide a row on the first sheet?

Comment: It looks as if it works, you have just turned it upside down in regard to what i was thinking but thank you! my only problem now is that if i run the code excel stops responding....

Comment: Will be a little faster if you add `Exit For` after the unhide step.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will run much faster if you do all the hiding at the end of the checking.

```
Sub HideCells()

    Dim xlRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim rngHide As Range, c As Range

    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Køb VT nummer")
    lastrow = xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("køb total")
    lastrow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In sht.Range("G2:G" & lastrow2)

        'any match on the other sheet?
        If IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, xlRange, 0)) Then
            If rngHide Is Nothing Then
                Set rngHide = c
            Else
                Set rngHide = Application.Union(rngHide, c)
            End If
        End If

    Next c

    'any rows to hide?  If Yes then hide them all
    If Not rngHide Is Nothing Then rngHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```